# Is there a way to use gplots::textplot with tables::tabular?

Tags: r, graphics

I would like to print a nice formatted table to a graphics device. I am aware there is `textplot()`, however it seems not to support the `tabular()` function from the `tables` package, which I use to assemble my table.

Is there a workaround, maybe another pair of functions that can help me here?

EDIT:
Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    id=paste("id", 1:10), 
    loc=sample(c("north", "south"), 10, replace=TRUE), 
    val1=rnorm(10), 
    val2=rnorm(10)
)
tab <- tabular(id + 1 ~ (val1 + val2)*loc*sum, data=dat)
#textplot(tab) # won't do it
```

(The call to tabular will become more complex, I am currently learning it step by step...)

Any hint appreciated! I am now thinking of using `text` with a monospaced fonts, but maybe there is something better?

EDIT2:
Here is the accepted solution:

```
textplot(capture.output(tab))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `capture.output` with the printed form of the `tabular` output then pass the result to textplot.  Or you could convert the result of tabular to a matrix and pass that to the `addtable2plot` function in the plotrix package.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on an update of `gridExtra::grid.table` that would support basic features of `tabular()`. You can try it:

```
# requires gtable
library(devtools) 
source_gist(2013903)
```

[image]

Comment: Where can I find the `gtable` package?

Answer (score 1):

The only graphics device that I know that would possibly accept LaTeX input is the `tikzDevice::tikz`. You might want to include the code your are sending to `tables::tabular` and we could see if the output is handled naturally.